# What is the difference between stateful service and state-aware service?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

To my understanding both terms describe the same thing, namely a service that retrieves and saves state in every operation call. But I could be wrong, so are there any differences between stateful and state-aware service?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of a distinction between the two. It's usually "stateful" for me.

And services work best when they're stateless - idempotent - right?

Comment: I thought transactional services most of times need to be state-aware?!

Comment: A service should own its unit of work and either commit or roll it back.  That need not mean state maintained between calls.  "Stateful" means "maintains state bewteen calls" to me.  Bad idea.